# How do I wrap span tags in a link_to in slim?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, slim-lang

```
li = link_to 'Account', '#account', data: { toggle: 'tab' }
```

I need span tags around 'Account'.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
li = link_to content_tag(:span, 'Account'), '#account', data: { toggle: 'tab' }
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-tag

Answer (score 30):

You can also use a block if you find that you have more complex code inside the link text than  just a **span** tag:

```
   li = link_to '#account', data: {toggle: 'tab'} do
     span
       = "Account"
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The key is to not put any string for the text in the first param to link_to. Instead, the content goes in the block.

Comment: Agreed with @justingordon.

Answer (score 1):

```
li = link_to "<span>Account</span>".html_safe, '#account', data: { toggle: 'tab' }
```

Comment: Not sure why this has been down-voted several times. Just because it might not be your preferred avenue, it's still a completely valid answer to the OP's question.